# (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) on ipad

Tags: swift, ipad

In my app I want users that have iPhones to be able to dial a number from a url, but if they are on a device that cannot dial out (such as certain users that I know are using iPad minis) then that number should be displayed to them instead.

How can I detect if they have ability to dial or not?
I'm trying with

```
if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
```

but that is not correct.

Here's my code:

```
if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel://\(self.waypoints[indexPath.row].phone!)") {
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
    if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
        alert_one.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call Customer Phone", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }))
    } else {
        print("iPads should reach this section")
        alert_one.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Phone: \(self.waypoints[indexPath.row].phone!)", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: why is `(application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL))` not correct?

Comment: because that is always true

Answer (score 1):

If you want "iPads should reach this section", start by asking whether this is an iPad:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
```